# XPTY0020: Finding root of tree: the context item is not a node

Tags: xslt

This error in XSLT has me stumped:

```
XPTY0020: Finding root of tree: the context item is not a node
```

My XSLT where it's saying the error is, is just a plain old variable declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="jmeterAvgTps"
                            select="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator[@id eq $currentId]/jmeter/tps/avg/text()" />
```

The XPATH is ok, I have checked it several times, and have used it in other places in the XSLT. Googling didn't reveal anything useful.

Full template:

```
<xsl:template name="populateJmeterStats">
<xsl:param name="currentHost"/>
<xsl:param name="currentAction" />
<xsl:param name="currentResult" />  
<xsl:param name="currentId" />  


                        <xsl:message>Populating jmeter stats: 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentHost"/>:
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentResult"/>:
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentAction"/>:
                        <xsl:value-of select="$currentId"/>:
                        </xsl:message>      
                                                        <xsl:if test="$currentAction='data'">

                        <xsl:if
                            test="$currentHost='jmeter'">   
                            <xsl:message>host is jmeter</xsl:message>

                        <xsl:variable name="jmeterAvgTps"
                            select="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator[@id eq $currentId]/jmeter/tps/avg/text()" />

                            <xsl:variable name="jmeterPercentileTps"
                                select="/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator[@id eq $currentId]/jmeter/tps/percentile/text()" />

                                <xsl:if test="$jmeterAvgTps">
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$jmeterAvgTps" />
                                    </td>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <xsl:if test="$jmeterPercentileTps">
                                    <td>

                                        <xsl:value-of select="$jmeterPercentileTps" />
                                    </td>

                                </xsl:if>

                            </xsl:if>

                                </xsl:if>
```

Comment: As it is a named template I am afraid that does not suffice to show us the change of any context item. But declare a global variable `<xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>` then use `<xsl:variable name="jmeterAvgTps"
                            select="$main-root/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator[@id eq $currentId]/jmeter/tps/avg/text()" />` and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare a global variable `<xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>` then use `<xsl:variable name="jmeterAvgTps" select="$main-root/summary/results[@count eq $currentResult]/simulator[@id eq $currentId]/jmeter/tps/avg/text()" />` and the problem should go away.

In XSLT 2.0 and later the context item can be a primitive value like a string or a number and in that case there is no way to access nodes of an input document other than storing it in a variable and accessing it.